# Transaction Foreign Key Causes: "INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint"

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How can I prevent the below error when executing a SQL Server transaction?

I'm trying to add a `SupplierOrder` and a `VehicleRecord` into a set of two database tables. I'm using the following:

#### Table SQL Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE VSI_VehicleRecords
(
    VehicleRecordID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    StockNumber INT NOT NULL,
    Status INT NOT NULL,
    Make VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Model VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Colour VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Spefication VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE VSI_SupplierOrders
(
    SupplierOrderID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    VehicleRecordID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES VSI_VehicleRecords(VehicleRecordID) UNIQUE,
    Timestamp
)
```

I've written a utility method which runs a set of Sql queries as a transaction:

#### C# Execution of a transaction:

```
    SqlTransaction _Transaction;
    OpenConnection();

    _Transaction = __Connection.BeginTransaction();

    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Commands.Length; i++)
        {
            Commands[i].Connection = __Connection;
            Commands[i].Transaction = _Transaction;
            Commands[i].ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        _Transaction.Commit();
        return true;
    }
    catch (SqlException e)
    {
        _Transaction.Rollback();
    }
```

#### SQL commands to be executed by the above function:

```
    SqlCommand[] _Commands = new SqlCommand[2];

    string _InsertVehicleQuery = "INSERT INTO VSI_VehicleRecords(StockNumber,Status,Make,Model,Colour,Spefication) VALUES (@StockNumber, @Status, @Make, @Model, @Colour, @Specification);";

    SqlCommand _InsertVehicleCommand = new SqlCommand(_InsertVehicleQuery);
    _InsertVehicleCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StockNumber", __StockNumber);
    _InsertVehicleCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", __Status);
    _InsertVehicleCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Make", Make);
    _InsertVehicleCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Model", Model);
    _InsertVehicleCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Colour", Colour);
    _InsertVehicleCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Specification", Specification);

    _Commands[0] = _InsertVehicleCommand;

    string _InsertSupplierOrderQuery = "INSERT INTO VSI_SupplierOrders(VehicleRecordID) VALUES (@VehicleRecordID);";
    SqlCommand _InsertSupplierOrderCommand = new SqlCommand(_InsertSupplierOrderQuery);
    _InsertSupplierOrderCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VehicleRecordID", _VehicleRecordID);

    _Commands[1] = _InsertSupplierOrderCommand;

    DataUtility.NonQueryTransaction(_Commands);
```

However I get the following error:

> *The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__VSI_Suppl_*Vehic*_5165187F". The conflict occurred in database
>   "jack_test", table "dbo.VSI_VehicleRecords", column 'VehicleRecordID'.*

Comment: How are you determining the `_VehicleRecordID` value that you're inserting in the second command?? If it's the `IDENTITY` from the previous command - how do you fetch / retrieve that???

Comment: @marc_s Prior to running the queries I use a "Select * MAX(...) .." query to determine the next primary key.

Comment: Jack - there is no reliable way to *determine the next primary key* when using an `IDENTITY` column. Due to concurrent activity in your system, or due to transaction that might have failed and been rolled back, the *next* value of an `IDENTITY` column is **not** always `MAX() + 1` ... don't use that technique - it's highly unreliable. Instead: let SQL Server do its work with the `IDENTITY` column and fetch the value that SQL Server has handed out. Only **after** the `INSERT` has actually happened is the "next" value of the `IDENTITY`  column really determined and can be read.

Comment: See podiluska's answer - that's the **only** reliable way to work with `IDENTITY` column: (1) insert your row into the table, (2) get the actual value that was inserted by using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` - nothing else will work reliably

Comment: Why are you using multiple commands?  Use one command.  Loop on load the command with parameters and execute the command.   And Select Scope_Identity is how to retrieve the Iden.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the VehicleRecordID from your first query - You currently aren't setting _VehicleRecordID to any value

To do that you need to append `;SELECT Scope_Identity()` after your insert SQL and execute the command via `ExecuteScalar`

However, it may be easier and neater to create a stored procedure that takes all the parameters for both queries and does the work on the SQL Server

eg

```
create proc CreateRecordAndSupplier
(
     @Stocknumber int,
     ... (etc)
)
as
begin
declare @VR int
      INSERT INTO VSI_VehicleRecords(StockNumber,Status,Make,Model,Colour,Spefication) 
      VALUES (@StockNumber, @Status, @Make, @Model, @Colour, @Specification);

      select @VR = Scope_Identity();

      INSERT INTO VSI_SupplierOrders(VehicleRecordID) VALUES (@VR) 
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this. I've not used stored procedures as of yet, so I'll have to do some reading!